# How to dump javascript data with functions to eval-able string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to dump this array to string and get the same object after evaluating it.

```
arr = [5, 86, function() { console.log(arguments); }, [console.log, 357]];
```

Although, functions may have extra properties, only the code is necessary to reproduce.

I can't find a way to do this in Node:

```
> console.log(arr)
[5, 86, [Function] [ [Function], 357] ]

> util.format('%j', arr)
'[5,86,null,[null,357]]'

> arr.toString()
'5,86,function () { console.log(arguments); },function () {\n  process.stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + \'\\n\');\n},357'
```

The latter has flatterned the array.

Is there a better way?

**update:** found the satisfying solution, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what satisfies me: **[jsDump](http://github.com/NV/jsDump)**

Answer (score 2):

JSON can't represent functions.  There's no way to put your array in JSON.  People often use the term "JSON" to mean any Javascript object literal.  It isn't: it's a strictly defined data format.

UPDATE: The OP has removed "JSON" from the title.

Comment: I've changed the question title. :)

Comment: I thought it could represent functions. Or is it BSON that can?
Because i used to store a function in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

as functions aren't a recognized JSON datatype you'll have to stringify them. here's an example from the wild: https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js/blob/master/main.js#L122

Answer (score 0):

If I have you right, you want to flatten it to a string, while retaining the original then convert it back to an array?

```
var original = ['a','b','c'];
var str = original.toString();
var newAgain = str.split(',');

console.log(original); //['a','b','c']
console.log(str);// "a,b,c"
console.log(newAgain); //['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Benvie/JASON

It won't have all the context necessary when code is inaccessible to you, but it will at least not throw reference errors when evaled.